# gulp-jasmine Window is not defined error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, gulp, gulp-jasmine

I am using gulp / gulp-jasmine / angular to run my unit tests. However, I encounter the following error when running my Gulp target:

```
C:\Projects\website2>gulp test
[01:53:10] Using gulpfile C:\Projects\website2\gulpfile.js
[01:53:10] Starting 'test'...
[01:53:11] Version: webpack 1.4.13
         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
test.bundle.js  1051728       0  [emitted]  test
F

Failures:
1) Exception loading: C:\Projects\website2\scripts\dist\test.bundle.js Error
1.1) ReferenceError: window is not defined

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.015 seconds
[01:53:11] 'test' errored after 916 ms
[01:53:11] Error in plugin 'gulp-jasmine'
Message:
    Tests failed
```

I believe gulp-jasmine uses PhantomJS (no browser window is triggered). Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?  Is there a configuration setting I'm missing?

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
var testWebpackConfig = require('./test.webpack.config');
var jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');

gulp.task('default', ['build'], function() {

});

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src(['scripts/app/**/*.js', '!scripts/app/**/*.tests.js'])
       .pipe(webpack(webpackConfig))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('scripts/dist'));
});

gulp.task('test', function() {
    return gulp.src(['scripts/app/**/*.tests.js'])
       .pipe(webpack(testWebpackConfig))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('scripts/dist'))       
       .pipe(jasmine());
});
```

Comment: Any progress on that issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I suspect the "window not defined" error has to do with Angular requiring the context of a browser and a working DOM in order to load properly.  jasmine is just a test framework.  I think you need a browser that provides a DOM API (i.e. window).  I found that PhantomJS works well for this.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gulp-jasmine runs the tests through Node.js and thus is not suitable for client side testing, see https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-jasmine/issues/46

For client side tests, if you want to use Jasmine (instead of Karma or in parallel), you can write a SpecRunner.html file (the name does not matter) and run it in your browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

    <!-- You need to specify package 'jasmine-core' in your Node.js package.json -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/images/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">

    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

    <!-- Source and Spec dependencies -->
    <script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <!-- Source files -->
    <script src="app/MySourceCode1.js"></script>
    <script src="app/MySourceCode2.js"></script>

    <!-- Spec files -->
    <script src="test/MySourceCode1.spec.js"></script>
    <script src="test/MySourceCode2.spec.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or use [gulp-jasmine-browser](https://github.com/jasmine/gulp-jasmine-browser):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// You need to specify packages 'jasmine-core' and 'gulp-jasmine-browser'
// in your Node.js package.json

gulp.task('jasmine', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'node_modules/underscore/underscore.js',
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

    'app/MySourceCode1.js',
    'app/MySourceCode2.js',
    'test/MySourceCode1.spec.js',
    'test/MySourceCode2.spec.js',
  ])
    .pipe($.jasmineBrowser.specRunner())
    .pipe($.jasmineBrowser.server());
});
```

Or use [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) :)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this another way using PhantomJS for the headless browser, karma for the command-line test runner, jasmine for the test framework, and gulp for the task runner.

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',

        files: [
            'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'index-controller.js',
            'index-controller.tests.js'
        ],

        exclude: [
        ],

        autoWatch: true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
        ],

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'unit.xml',
            suite: 'unit'
        }

    })
}
```

Install the necessary npm modules:

```
npm install angular
npm install angular-mocks
npm install -g gulp
npm install gulp
npm install karma
npm install -g karma-cli
npm install karma-jasmine
npm install karma-junit-reporter
npm install karma-chrome-launcher
npm install karma-firefox-launcher
npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher
npm install phantomjs
```

Update your gulpfile.js and provide two tasks: the default task to run the unit tests once, a TDD task to watch the file system and run the tests when any file changes:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma').server;
gulp.task('default', function(done) {
  karma.start({      
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js', 
        singleRun: true 
   }, done); 

});

gulp.task('tdd', function (done) { 
   karma.start({ 
     configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js' 
   }, done); 
});
```

To trigger:

```
gulp default
gulp tdd
```

For completeness, here is my index-controller, and associated test:

**index-controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.name = 'mickey mouse';
});
```

**index-controller.tests.js**

```
describe('index-controller', function() {
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the 
        // parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.name', function() {
        it('should be mickey mouse', function() {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('ctrl', { $scope: $scope });

            expect($scope.name).toEqual('mickey mouse');
        });

  });
});
```

Comment: Karma `require`s everything in `node_module` that starts `karma-`, so you ought not to need the `plugins` section of the config, unless you have `node_modules/karma-*` you need to exclude but cannot remove.